# Strategy for permanent links (not wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I'm building a little database driven PHP CMS. I'm trying to figure the best strategy for this case scenario:

I have a URL like this:

`http://www.my.com/news/cool-slug`

Someone saves or share this URL (or it gets indexed by Google).

Now I realize that the slug is not quite right and change it to:

`http://www.my.com/news/coolest-slug`

Google and users who previously saved the URL will hit a `404` error.

Is this the best and common solution (showing the 404) or should I keep a table in my database with all the history of the generated URLs mapped to the ID of the page and redirect with a `301` header?
Will this be an unnecessary load on my system (this table can get lots of records...)?

Comment: Depends on the site really, traffic-wise and their user base. It could be more performant to just store it's previous slug next to the current one rather than a full history for everything.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to make a redirect in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php/768472#768472)

Comment: But should I worry and build a system to redirect old URLs to the new ones or should I just let them hit a 404? What do systems like Wordpress do?

Answer (score 0):

One very common solution used by many sites (including StackOverflow as far as I can tell) is to include the ID in the URL. The slug is just here for SEO/beauty/whatever, but is not used to identify the page.

Example: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877901/strategy-for-permanent-links-not-wordpress`

As long as you have the right ID, it doesn't matter what slug you use. The site will just detect that the slug is wrong, and generate a redirect to the right one. For example, the following URL is valid:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877901/old-slug`

If for some reason you do not want the ID in the URL, then either you forbid changes (many news site do that: you can notice that sometimes the slug and the title of a news article do not match), or your have to live with the occasional 404 when the slug changes. I've never seen any website having a system to keep the slug history, as it can be quite annoying (you won't be able to "reuse" a slug for example).

Comment: Wordpress keeps track of these slug changes for posts. It uses the `wp_postmeta` table and adds the `_wp_old_slug` key related to the post_id. I think that it searches this table if no other match is found before it shows a 404.